# Scala class path mixup java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something in Scala with apparat library. The library is in /Applications/apparat. Compilation happens OK, imports are OK, but I still get this error when I run it.

```
scalac -classpath /Applications/apparat/\* SimpleObject.scala 
scala -cp . SimpleObject hello.swf

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apparat/utils/TagContainer$
```

Script:

```
  import apparat.utils.TagContainer


  object SimpleObject {
      def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

        val tags = TagContainer.fromFile( args(0) )

     }
  }
```

I'm pretty sure I miss something either when compiling or when running it. If I use command line interpreter then the script works fine and I don't get any erros. For example  can do this:

```
scala -cp /Applications/apparat/\*
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.RC3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import apparat.utils.TagContainer
import apparat.utils.TagContainer

scala> val tag = TagContainer.fromFile("hello.swf")
tag: apparat.utils.TagContainer = apparat.utils.TagContainer@533790eb
```

Comment: Why aren't you adding `/Applications/apparat/\*` to the classpath when you call `scala`?

Comment: if I do scala -cp /Applications/apparat/\* SimpleObject hello.swf then it says SimpleOBject not found. I guess it starts looking for the script I want to run in that directory

Answer (score 0):

```
scala -classpath /Applications/apparat/\*:. SimpleObject hello.swf
```

though I thought wild cards were not allowed in class paths.

Comment: Wildcards work in some cases, but it's safer to specify all the jar's. Which is another very annoying thing so I have exported a variable for that.

Comment: I think thats a new thing as of Java 6

Comment: In fact I found that wildcard worked nicely when I ran it as script, but not when I ran as compiled program. Maybe just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it. Need to put current directory into the -cp (:.) as Daniel says when compiling. Also, when running the -cp has to point to same class path.

Comment: Actually, that was a typo on my part. It shouldn't be necessary on compilation, just execution.

Comment: Needs to be on compilation as well, it complains on imports otherwise.